# Box of listing starts one page too early

Tags: listings

I have the problem, that the box of a listing starts one page too early:
[image: pagebreak]

Is it possible to allow the listing spreading over two pages, but not if there is an "empty line"?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}    % instead of babel
\setdefaultlanguage[]{english}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[framed, numbered, mlscaleinline=true]{matlab-prettifier}
%\usepackage{listings}
\definecolor{MatlabCellColour}{RGB}{252,251,220}

\lstset{% general command to set parameter(s)
style          = Matlab-editor,
backgroundcolor= \color{MatlabCellColour}
}

\begin{document}
\Blindtext[5]
AA

AA

\begin{lstlisting}
for i=0:2
    % ...
end
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you comfortable using `float=t` for that particular listing? Something like `\begin{lstlisting}[float=tb]`?

Comment: Thank you for this hint! But in my original document the listing is then placed three pages later and it should set be exactly after the preceding text. I know that `\newpage` would "work", but this is not a solution.